# Store IN parameter in variable of Stored procedure

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures

I am creating a Stored procedure in which ,

I am passing 2 IN parameters as 'year' & 'month' to a procedure,

then " I need to store these both IN parameters in one variable in date_format like ('YYYY-MM-DD')."

And after that I want to use that variable with that Date_Format.

I will try to explain above things in stored procedures format

```
CREATE PROCEDURE build_table(IN years CHAR(5) ,IN months CHAR(4))
BEGIN
DECLARE format1 date ;

# Now i want to store both IN parameters in 'format1' variable and then format1 should be in format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

Can I do this in stored procedure?

If yes give me some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tru to use this variant -

```
SET @year = 2012;
SET @month = 2;
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@year, '-', @month), '%Y-%c');
```

The [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function will help you to make a date value. Change @year and @month variables with IN parameters.

Then you can use a DATE_FORMAT function to format datetime value, e.g.:

```
SET @year = 2012;
SET @month = 2;
SET @dt = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@year, '-', @month), '%Y-%c');
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@dt, '%m/%d/%Y');
+------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(@dt, '%m/%d/%Y') |
+------------------------------+
| 02/00/2012                   |
+------------------------------+
```

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE build_table(IN years CHAR(5), IN months CHAR(4))
BEGIN
  DECLARE format1 date;
  SET format1 = DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(years, '-', months, '-01'), '%Y-%c-%e'), INTERVAL 1 DAY);


  SELECT format1;
END

CALL build_table(2012, 1);
+------------+
| format1    |
+------------+
| 2011-12-31 | -- default format is 'YYYY-MM-DD'
+------------+
```

Comment: ok, it means I will pass 2 IN parameters let say 'y' and 'm' with char data-type then i will set them to like `set @y=2012; set @m=2;` am I considering in right way? and I want to store `STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@year, '-', @month), '%Y-%c'); ` in another variable as I need to use it in select clause afterwords

Comment: I will add the stored procedure

Comment: Also, you may use INT data type instead of CHAR.

Comment: yes sure, I am trying your str_date function in this way as i want to find out `last_date_of_previous month` means if we pass '2012' as year and '01' as month as a IN parameter this ` SET format1 = DATE_SUB( STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(years, '-', months), '%Y-%M-%d'),INTERVAL 1 DAY);` will give me date as '2011-12-31' , which I am not getting , though procedure executes, why is it so?

Comment: I have debugged the procedure and have seen two mistakes. 1 - The day should be added (to STR_TO_DATE function). 2 - CAST function should be used. I modified my answer.